# Error in removing overlaping rectangles in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, image-segmentation

I was trying to remove overlapping rectangles in an image post segmentation.

```
%find and remove overlapping regions
for i=1:groupRectsCt-1
        if(currentRect(1,1)>=cRect(1,1) & currentRect(1,1)+currentRect(1,3)<=cRect(1,1)+cRect(1,3))
            flag =1; break;
        end
        if(currentRect(1,1)<=cRect(1,1) & currentRect(1,1)+currentRect(1,3)>=cRect(1,1)+cRect(1,3))
            candiRect(j,:) = currentRect; flag =1; break;
        end
    if(flag) continue; end
    candiRect(candiCt,:) = currentRect;
end
```

But  I don't know how to define  condition for `currentRec`.
I wanted to define a loop for selecting a rectangle from left to right or any way of selecting the value for current rectangle.
Something like

```
  currentRect = groupRects(sortId?
```

Could you advise?

Comment: First you can check [rectint](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/rectint.html). Then you should be more clear in your question.

Comment: Could you post you sample image as well, please.